# Selecting a Network Interface with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, networking, network-programming

I want to connect to two different GoPro cameras using my computer's integrated network card and a USB drive wifi adapter (GoPros connect through Wifi). both GoPros receive commands through the same IP address, 10.5.5.9. So, if I get_ip_address on both available cameras, they return the same result - and as far as I can see, this invalidates using socket to select an interface, which seems to be the most common/popular response to question like this on the interwebs. What I usually see for a potential solution is

```
s1 = socket.socket()
s1.bind((get_ip_address('gopro1'), 0))
s1.connect(('url', 0))
```

...except that, as I said, the IP address is the same. So this doesn't select an interface at all; all it can do it open a connection from whatever the 'default' interface is. (Sending commands through this I think would be simple, since they're all sent as URLs, but if it only ever goes through one camera, than the point is defeated.)

I'm not sure where to go with this, or have many more ideas of how to phrase it differently for Google. How can I control traffic through two different interfaces with identical IP addresses?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're connecting to a remote host, you should not need to bind to a specific interface locally.

Comment: What do you mean? When I have each interface connected to a different camera, sending commands to the camera only works through one of the interfaces. It'll connect to both one at a time (if I leave the second off, for example), so I know my program works - it seems entirely to be a network issue.

Comment: Let me get this straight... None of your cameras are *physically* connected to your computer, e.g. with a cable? And you try to use the address of one of the cameras as the interface to bind to? Then that's not possible. You need to get the address of one of the *local* interfaces, one of the network cards physically connected (one way or another) to your computer. Even then you might not be able to connect if your local network and the camera network is not the same.

Comment: And can't you change the configuration in the cameras? So they have different IP addresses, or uses DHCP?  Few wifi-connected things made in the last decade or so doesn't allow DHCP or manual configuration.

Comment: Nope, they're both connected via Wifi to two separate interfaces (for example, wl20s and wl40p, retrieved using `netifaces.interfaces()`). I am trying to use a camera address to bind, but I realize that's probably incorrect. As far as changing the IP address- I have seen something similar for the GoPro Hero 3, but GPH4 uses a different API, and haven't seen anything for that yet (haven't looked a whole lot since it just occurred to me to check as well). As for DHCP, I'm not familiar enough with networking to know what that entails or means without some research...

Comment: GPH seems very rigid in their setups, though. You can't change much about how the Wifi works or connects. There's a Bluetooth functionality, but as far as I can tell it doesn't actually work for anything (except maybe their app, which can't connect to multiple simultaneously either, so not sure why they'd include both BT and Wifi).